# install plugins in eclipse won't work

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

i get strange errors, when i try to install the android adt in eclipse 3.7 (indigo). the error occurs, whenever i try to install sth - which is basically EVERYTHING:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found. Software currently installed: Shared profile 1.0.0.1308118821836 (SharedProfile_epp.package.java 1.0.0.1308118821836)
Missing requirement: Shared profile 1.0.0.1308118821836 (SharedProfile_epp.package.java 1.0.0.1308118821836) requires 'org.maven.ide.eclipse [1.0.0.20110607-2117]' but it could not be found
```

so i downloaded eclipse again, deleted the whole workspace, even reinstalled the java sdk... same error :(
i also tried to install maven from the "eclipse marketplace", but i got the same exact error :(

could this be due to some registry cleanup stuff? i cleaned the registry using "regseeker"...

ah: btw: win 7 x64 with sp1, running eclipse x68 and java x86 (due to other problems with x64-versions)

someone knows an answer to this?

Comment: I tried install ADT in my indigo and my OS is win7 but it's success.

Comment: What's the detailed process how you install it?

Comment: Try running Eclipse as Administrator or placing it somewhere where in your user folder (c:\Users\yourusername\) where Windows does not restrict write operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a [bug in Eclipse 3.7](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=350380) that has been fixed in Eclipse 3.7.1

Take a look at the [workaround documented in the bug comments](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=350380#c8):

> The current workaround is to start from a package that does not include m2e
>   (like the Eclipse SDK), mark the install read only, and then install into it
>   the things that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's something weird going on with the Maven integration that's only in the Java package.  Try starting with a different one, such as the Java EE package, and if that works, report this as a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run Eclipse as Administrator or give your "eclipse" folder write permissions to all users.
Have a look at this question: [Plugins won't install on Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638321/plugins-wont-install-on-eclipse)