# Plugins won't install on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-indigo

I am trying to install subversive and checkstyle onto Eclipse IDE for Java Developers however the following message appears:

"Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software currently installed: Shared profile 1.0.0.1316138460759 (SharedProfile_epp.package.java 1.0.0.1316138460759)
Missing requirement: Shared profile 1.0.0.1316138460759 (SharedProfile_epp.package.java 1.0.0.1316138460759) requires 'org.maven.ide.eclipse [1.0.100.20110804-1717]' but it could not be found"

What does it mean? Is there another way to install them as I need both plugins for my course.

Please help and thank you :)

Comment: trying from you local location or from update site? if former then  you need  to have the dependency, else it should take care.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try running Eclipse as administrator, I just had the same issue and this worked for me.

Answer (score 11):

There's an alternative to running Eclipse as an administrator: you can manually give write permissions to your "eclipse" folder for all users (or just your current user).
This way Windows/UAC won't pop up the security question that you see when you run programs as admin.

Comment: I've added myself as a user with all permissions, and it works quite well! But I've had to restart eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

Hi I had the same problem just yesterday. 
I was uploading SDK for android and found your question in a google search.

I reverted back to an older version of eclipse. [Link to older version of eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/helios/SR2/eclipse-java-helios-SR2-win32-x86_64.zip)

This solved it for me.

Remember to delete eclips from your program files. You do this by just physically deleting the file from program files (not through uninstall). Then also make sure you delete your workbench. This is a file called workbench in your docs. Well mine was in my docs, it could be somewhere else on your system.

I am using windows 7.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, but I had to dig harder to fix it.

The source of my problem was the shortcut to launch Eclipse had this in the Target field:

> "C:\Program Files\eclipse\eclipse.exe" -configuration C:\Program
>   Files\eclipse\configuration

The problem with this is that without double quotes around the "-configuration C:\Program Files\eclipse\configuration" section it would hit that space in 'Program Files' and use C:\Program for storing configuration some of the time. Generally, if you have C:\Program you should make sure programs didn't put random files in there by mistake.

To fix this I had to move the configuration files from C:\Program to C:\Program Files\eclipse\configuration, picking and choosing along the way. Change the Target field to:

> "C:\Program Files\eclipse\eclipse.exe" "-configuration C:\Program
>   Files\eclipse\configuration"

and I was good to go.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I solved it by setting

"Contact all update sites during install to find required software"

to true.

(I used the Eclipse install manager, in 
  Eclipse IDE for Java Developers,
  Version: Indigo Service Release 1
)

Comment: Thank you, this helped me. Although i still always have to disable my firewall even with Eclipse given 100% permission.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, updating to the latest version of Eclipse (Juno) did the trick. Perhaps your add-on won't run on your version?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the maven plugin in order to install your plugin. If that's the case, you can follow this [this instruction](http://judygichoya.posterous.com/maven-installation-into-eclipse-1) to install it.

Comment: I tried installing the maven plugin and used the instructions that you provided but it came up with exactly the same error. Thanks for the link though

Answer (score 0):

Use eclipse update manager to install the plugins.. Then it will automatically select dependent plugins..You dont need to bother about dependent plugins in that case

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was completely open up full permissions for all users to the directory.  This is dangerous if you have a multi-user system but Windows 7 seems to default to giving processes not very high permission levels; some processes (such as Eclipse Updated) don't know how to deal with this and request user permission, so they just bomb out.  Easy fix: full control to all users and processes for the Eclipse Directory.