# Conflicting dependency while eclipse updating; Common Navigator View installed threee times

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, updates

Cannot do check for updates because of following error:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Eclipse Java Development Tools 3.7.2.v20120120-1414-7z8gFcuFMP7BW5XTz0jLTnz0l9B1 (org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group 3.7.2.v20120120-1414-7z8gFcuFMP7BW5XTz0jLTnz0l9B1)
  Software currently installed: Shared profile 1.0.0.1317160331466 (SharedProfile_PlatformProfile 1.0.0.1317160331466)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Common Navigator View 3.5.100.v20110809-2227 (org.eclipse.ui.navigator 3.5.100.v20110809-2227)
    Common Navigator View 3.5.100.I20110524-0800 (org.eclipse.ui.navigator 3.5.100.I20110524-0800)
    Common Navigator View 3.5.101.v20120106-1355 (org.eclipse.ui.navigator 3.5.101.v20120106-1355)
    Common Navigator View 3.5.100.dist (org.eclipse.ui.navigator 3.5.100.dist)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Shared profile 1.0.0.1317160331466 (SharedProfile_PlatformProfile 1.0.0.1317160331466)
    To: org.eclipse.ui.navigator [3.5.100.dist]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Java Development Tools 3.7.2.v20120120-1414-7z8gFcuFMP7BW5XTz0jLTnz0l9B1 (org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group 3.7.2.v20120120-1414-7z8gFcuFMP7BW5XTz0jLTnz0l9B1)
    To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.7.2
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.7.2.v20120207-1839-9gF7UHPDFxGjd-PqDr2jX_4yKaumkoHTz04_q-q (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.7.2.v20120207-1839-9gF7UHPDFxGjd-PqDr2jX_4yKaumkoHTz04_q-q)
    To: org.eclipse.ui.navigator [3.5.101.v20120106-1355]
```

Cannot find no any `Common Navigator View` to uninstall in `Eclipse Platform Installation Deatails` on `Installed Software` tab.

No any entry in this dialog allows uninstall either.

I see `Common Navigator View` entry in `Plug-ins` tab of this dialog, but this tab does not allow to uninstall anything. Also I see `Common Navigator View` only once there (not three times).

How to resolve the situation?

OS is Ubuntu 11.10 and probably `Eclipse` was installed via build in package manager (don't remember).

Answer (score 0):

From the description it seems like you are trying to install "Java Development Tools", which requires navigator 3.5.101 while it seems like you have some kind of shared installation of plugins and one of those plugins requires a different version of navigator (3.5.100). I would suggest you to either uninstall that plugin which is causing this conflict or try installing a  slightly older version of JDT which may accept the currently installed 3.5.100 version.

Comment: You might want to also have a look at this issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638321/plugins-wont-install-on-eclipse