# Unable to install plugins for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, amazon-web-services, eclipse-plugin

I am unable to install Amazon SDK ToolKit for eclipse. I followed the instructions [here](http://aws.amazon.com/eclipse/). But after installing some packages, eclipse gives the following error

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software currently installed: Amazon SimpleDB Management 1.0.0.v201401072240 (com.amazonaws.eclipse.datatools.enablement.simpledb.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.v201401072240)
Missing requirement: Eclipse Data Tools Platform Amazon SimpleDB UI Plug-in 1.0.0.v201401072240 (com.amazonaws.eclipse.datatools.enablement.simpledb.ui 1.0.0.v201401072240) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.sqlscrapbook 1.0.0' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Amazon SimpleDB Management 1.0.0.v201401072240 (com.amazonaws.eclipse.datatools.enablement.simpledb.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.v201401072240)
To: com.amazonaws.eclipse.datatools.enablement.simpledb.ui [1.0.0.v201401072240]
```

I am using Eclipse Juno. What is wrong here? I even tried opening the eclipse.exe directly as the 'Administrator', as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638321/plugins-wont-install-on-eclipse). Still it is not working.

Comment: Is the checkbox allowing Eclipse to contact all known update sites enabled? Is the Juno Update Site one of the known sites?

Comment: @nitind: sorry? I didn't understand.

Comment: @nitind: ahh, you mean "contact all update sites during install and find required software" ? Yes, it is checkd.

Comment: Do you have the Juno update site in the list of available update site? The message is saying it needs the `org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.sqlscrapbook` plugin which is part of `Eclipse Data Tools Platform` which should be in the Juno update site.

Comment: @greg-449: and How can I add it if it is not there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check out the [Getting Started Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSToolkitEclipse/latest/GettingStartedGuide/tke_setup.html), we recommend that you start with the Java EE version of Eclipse. The SimpleDB tools depend on the Data Tools Platform.

Comment: Hello, here I am again. I faced an issue in accessing Amazon RDS using Eclipse. My question is here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21307937/unable-to-connect-to-rds-database-java-lang-reflect-invocationtargetexception. Please help

Answer (score 3):

In case you are not using Java EE version of eclipse as recommended, you can add the needed `data tools platform` by clicking on Help and then click on Install new Software and add

`http://download.eclipse.org/datatools/updates/1.11`

and then proceeding with Amazon SDK ToolKit for eclipse.

Comment: I just went through this, and it turns out that the newer versions of the data tools platform does not work. `1.12` does not work with this.