# Unable to access Amazon RDS using Eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I just installed MySQL in Amazon RDS, using its wizards. I selected the same security group my EC2 instance is using.

I tried to access this by Eclipse AWS toolkit. What I did is right clicking on the RDS instance and clicked on "Conenct". Then it asked for the password and tried to connect, but ended up with the below error.

```
Unable to connect to RDS database
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

I have seen number of posts regarding this without having a single solution.

Answer (score 0):

I hope your machine IP is part of aws security rule. Please also check the respective ports are not blocked by your firewall..

Answer (score 0):

You probably gave access to your ec2 security group, but not your local ip address. RDS does not use ec2 security groups, but I can open access to an ec2 security group.

Comment: OK, How to give that permission? Local ip permission? please help.

Comment: You can do this in the RDS console. Look under the section titled security groups.

Comment: I can't see such a section

Comment: Are you looking in eclipse? The RDS console is here: https://console.aws.amazon.com/rds/home?region=us-east-1#security:

Comment: I am not mentioning to the console. I can't see a place to edit the security group, it is only available when we are creating the db instance

Comment: And I selected the option 'publically accessible' when creating the instance

Comment: Do I have to install "MySQL Connector/J" ?

Comment: You are probably mentioning to the old console.