# Installing IDE eclipse plugin for Bazaar via eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, bazaar

I wanted to install eclipse plugin for Bazaar and every time i do it there comes an error:

> " Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software currently installed: Shared profile
>   1.0.0.1399191266286 (SharedProfile_epp.package.php 1.0.0.1399191266286)    Missing requirement: Shared profile 1.0.0.1399191266286 (SharedProfile_epp.package.php 1.0.0.1399191266286) requires 'SharedProfile_epp.package.php [1.0.0.1399152407353]' but it could not be found "

....    I have tried even to change eclipse folder location, but it didn't help. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

To install or update plugins in Eclipse, you must run the program as **administrator** (cf. [Plugins won't install on Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638321/plugins-wont-install-on-eclipse)).